# Trading view library is not working on Production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg-v2

i have used trading view  charting library in react
its working perfect in development but in production its not working

when i used yarn build these warnings came in console but build successfully created

failed to parse source map from 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-flow-extension\constants.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-flow-extension\constants.ts'

Failed to parse source map from 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-flow-extension\contributions\flow.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-flow-extension\contributions\flow.tsx'

Failed to parse source map from 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-flow-extension\index.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-flow-extension\index.tsx'

Failed to parse source map from 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-flow-extension\module.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-flow-extension\module.ts'

Failed to parse source map from 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-flow-extension\x6-extension\node.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-flow-extension\x6-extension\node.ts'

Failed to parse source map from 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-json-schema-form\constants.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-json-schema-form\constants.ts'

Failed to parse source map from 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-json-schema-form\index.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-json-schema-form\index.tsx'

Failed to parse source map from 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-json-schema-form\interface.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\MicroMerger\Stock Exchange Real Project\realStockExchange\node_modules@antv\xflow-extension\src\canvas-json-schema-form\interface.tsx'

like these there are more

Comment: None of the [results when searching for that error](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Failed+to+parse+source+map+from%22) helped? What have you tried to fix them? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: no solution yet

Comment: try removing spaces from folder name

Comment: what do you mean by remove spaces?